# Objective-C 101: dot notation and object properties

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have a very basic question regarding properties in Objective-C.

I can only access object's properties via dot notation (`Obj.MyProp`) if I `@synthesize` `myProp`. Is that correct?

Would it be true to say that if I use my own setter method, I will no longer be able to refer to property in dot notation?

Basically I am looking for C# type of functionality where I can write my own custom getter/setter and yet provide an additional code which I need to execute when the property is set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@property creates automatic message declarations, just like writing

```
(int)thing;
(void)setThing:(int)value;
```

@synthesize automatically creates the implementations, i.e.

```
(int)thing {
    return thing;
}
(void)setThing:(int)value {
    thing = value;
}
```

If you give a definition yourself, it overrides the @synthesized version. So as long as you name a method correctly, it will work, with or without @synthesize in there.

Dot notation works with either synthesized or custom method implementations.

Comment: A thing to note here is that the actual name setThing is important. If your setter has a different name, you can override that with the setter attribute of the @property declaration.

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct. You can still use dot-notation even if you write custom getters or setters provided of course that your getters and setters maintain the correct method naming for the property.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html):

> @synthesize
>
> You use the @synthesize keyword to tell the compiler that it should
>   synthesize the setter and/or getter
>   methods for the property if you do not
>   supply them within the @implementation
>   block.

It only synthesizes if you haven't already written them. If you've written them, they don't get synthesized.

Comment: as long as your getters and setters are KVC compliant for getters and setters, dot notation should work.

Comment: What's that got to do with @synthesize?